# Object in next result set of Jscroll doenot bind to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-jscroll

I have implemented jquery jscroll on first page load all data is showing perfectly with the perfect respective animation but on 2nd data set animations are not working. What I am doing is i have made a partial page which loads all time the data set comes and set all javascript in main page.

This is my MainPage code

```
<script src="~/Content/JavaScript/Caption.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        //for each description div...
        $('div.description').each(function () {
            //...set the opacity to 0...
            $(this).css('opacity', 0);
            //..set width same as the image...
            $(this).css('width', $(this).siblings('img').width());
            //...get the parent (the wrapper) and set it's width same as the image width... '
            $(this).parent().css('width', $(this).siblings('img').width());
            //...set the display to block
            $(this).css('display', 'block');
        });

        $('div.wrapper').hover(function () {
            //when mouse hover over the wrapper div
            //get it's children elements with class descriptio
            //and show it using fadeTo
            $(this).children('.description').stop().fadeTo(500, 0.7);
        }, function () {
            //when mouse out of the wrapper div
            //use fadeTo to hide the div
            $(this).children('.description').stop().fadeTo(500, 0);
        });

    });

</script>
<style>
    div.wrapper {
        position: relative; /* important(so we can absolutely position the description div */
    }

    div.description {
        position: absolute; /* absolute position (so we can position it where we want)*/
        bottom: 0px; /* position will be on bottom */
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        display: none; /* hide it */
        /* styling bellow */
        background-color: black;
        font-family: 'tahoma';
        font-size: 15px;
        color: white;
    }

    div.description_content {
        padding: 10px;
    }
</style>



<div class="row">

        <div class="scroll">
            @Html.Partial("_Products")
        </div>

    </div> <!-- .main-content -->

<script src="~/Content/JavaScript/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/JavaScript/jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/JavaScript/jquery.jscroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 0;

    //Get Value From Query String
    function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    function Filter() {
        var goto = updateTextArea();
        var addpricerangefilter = UpdateQueryString("price_range", document.getElementById('PriceRangeFrom').value +'-'+ document.getElementById('PriceRangeTo').value, goto)
        window.location = addpricerangefilter
    }
    $(function () {
        $('.scroll').jscroll({
            debug: true,
            autoTrigger: false
        });
    });

</script>
```

Partial Page

```
@Code
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    Dim CurrencyCODE As String = "INR"
    Dim CurrencyRATE As String = 1
    Try
        CurrencyCODE = Request.Cookies("currency_code").Value.ToString
        CurrencyRATE = Val(Request.Cookies("currency_rate").Value.ToString)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Code
    @For Each AllProducts In ViewBag.lstProducts
        @<div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="single-item">
                @If AllProducts.ItemTag <> "" Then
                    @<div class="ribbon-wrapper"><div style="background-color:@AllProducts.ItemTagColor;" class="ribbon">@AllProducts.ItemTag</div></div>
                End If
                <div class="single-item-header wrapper">
                    @Code
                        Dim ImagePath = AllProducts.SKUID &"00.jpg"
                    End Code
                    <a href="/SingleProduct/Index?sku_code=@AllProducts.SKUID"><img src="/Content/Images/ProductImage/@ImagePath" class="image270320" alt="@AllProducts.ItemShortDesc"></a>
                    <div class="description">
                        <div class="description_content">
                                @AllProducts.ItemShortDesc
                            <a class="add-to-cart pull-right auto-width-right" href="#" onclick="AddToCart('@AllProducts.SKUID','1')"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart shopcart"></i></a>
                            <a class="add-to-cart pull-right auto-width-right" href="#" onclick="AddToWishList('@AllProducts.SKUID')"><i class="fa fa-heart favorlist"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="single-item-body">
                    <p class="single-item-title">
                        @AllProducts.SKUID
                    </p>
                    <p class="single-item-price">
                        @If AllProducts.ItemDiscountedPrice <> "0" And AllProducts.ItemDiscountedPrice <> "" Then
                            @<span class="flash-del">@CurrencyCODE @Math.Round(CurrencyRATE * AllProducts.ItemOrignalPrice, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)</span>
                            @<span class="flash-sale">@CurrencyCODE @Math.Round(CurrencyRATE * AllProducts.ItemDiscountedPrice, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)</span>
                        Else
                            @<span>@CurrencyCODE @Math.Round(CurrencyRATE * AllProducts.ItemOrignalPrice, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)</span>
                        End If

                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        If i = 3 Then
            @<div class="space40">&nbsp;</div>
            i=0
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next
@If ViewBag.lstProducts.Count > 0 Then
@<div style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;height :5px;margin-top :5px;padding-left:400px">
     <a href="/Product/PartialViewData?category_id=@Request.QueryString("category_id")&order_by=@Request.QueryString("order_by")&group_name=@Request.QueryString("group_name")&page_no=@ViewBag.PageNo&detail_id=@Request.QueryString("detail_id")&price_range=@Request.QueryString("price_range")&sku=@Request.QueryString("sku")">Load More Products...</a>
</div>
Else
@<div style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;height :5px;margin-top :5px;padding-left:400px">
    Oops we are at the end of product list!!!
</div>
End If
```

What I try is copying all scripts in partial page but it won't work

Comment: Far too much code here to wade through. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: when I put the minimal code people keep asking for the code which is not even related to my question like for some variable they ask what that variable stores and etc. so this time i put it all

Comment: Though I have minimized my code